# How can i give slash in input string of ios

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *str=@"\kss)Äjiyxjkogngqx%oz(xz)ll&\egffp}ij&}iw*tzhimx#A";
```

`str` is my input string, i get the warning

> "Unknown escape sequence \k"

How should i rewrite the input string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the slash like so

```
@"\\"
```

So your string should be

```
NSString str=@"\\kss)Äjiyxjkogngqx%oz(xz)ll&\\egffp}ij&}iwtzhimx#A";
```

Here is a better example that should help

```
  NSString* str = @"\\a\\b\\";
  NSLog(@"%@ %d",str,str.length);
  NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",[str substringFromIndex:0],[str substringFromIndex:1],[str substringFromIndex:2]);
```

Should output

```
  \a\b\ 5
  \a\b\ a\b\ \b\
```

The string will be stored internally as "\a\b\".

Comment: Yes i did this, but i need to decrypt the exact string. so am not able to add extra slashes to escape the string.

Comment: Please post encryption decryption code also

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, you enter this string yourself right?

if so, adding the extra slashes should mean that internally it is only a single slash.

    NSString* str = @"\\";
    NSLog(@"%@ %d",str,str.length);

should print 

    \ 1

Comment: @IOSdeveloper : now can you check it

Comment: Thanks, all works fine.The escaping character decrypted correctly.

Comment: Please select my answer if it helped you. It helps the next visitor to the question!